# Does having a method that updates and add new record if the record does not exist break SRP?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a DatabaseService class that has Update(user) and Add(user). 
My question is about having them both in one method. Is it a good practice or not ? 
To be more specific does it break the singularity rule (i.e. Single Responsibility)?
For example if i have a mothed like this

```
public void AddOrUpdateUser(User user) 
{
   var userFound = GetUserById(user.Id); 
   if (userFound == null) 
   {
      AddUser(user); 
   }
   else
   {
      UpdateUser(user); 
   }
}
```

Would it be a good idea ? or would it be bad because it breaks the singularity rule so let the consumer class decides what to do?

Comment: Design wise it would be better to add a 'Persist()' method to the User class and have it determine if it has been previously persisted or not. If it has, it would do an Update, if not, an Add. This way the user of the User class could simply call 'user.Persist()' without having to concern itself with knowing whether an Add or Update should be performed.

Comment: Depends on the DBMS you are using. And if you might think about introducing an `IsNew`-flag in your objects...

Comment: You do not want AddOrUpdateUser method inside DatabaseService class. Instead, you can have AddOrUpdateUser method inside UI layer.

Comment: I liked the idea of @user469104 having Persist inside class User, but then to implement it you need an instance of the DatabaseService inside it , right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's common to work this way. If given user it hasn't been already persisted, it'll be created, otherwise, it'll be updated.

BTW, I would change the part of getting a possible user by given `Id` with something like this:

```
public interface IPersistable
{
     bool IsNew { get; }
}

public class User : IPersistable
{
    public int Id { get; set; };
    public bool IsNew => Id == 0; 
}
```

And then:

```
IPersistable persistable = user as IPersistable;
Contract.Assert(persistable != null);

if(persistable.IsNew)
{
    // Create
}
else
{
   // Update
}
```

### OP concerns about single responsibility principle (SRP)

Since we call this method as `AddOrUpdate`, OP has said in some comment on my answer that this could break *single responibility principle*.

I really believe that this concern comes from the method identifier rather than of what the method really does.

The whole method takes care of persisting objects and, from the consumer point of view, this is a single responsibility: *I want you to take care about persisting my object*.

Either if it was already on the underlying store or not, it's still *persisting an object*. We could rename this method to `Persist`, `Save` or whatever, but `AddOrUpdate`, at least, provides more semantics to the operation and it follows another unofficial (but widely accepted) principle: **self-documented code** (you can understand what your code does just by reading the code itself).

Thus, it seems like it would break *single responsibility principle* if it would also delete objects or any other unrelated operation that could be represented by another *verb*.

Comment: Uhm.. IsDirty should be used if an Object actually changed one of its values... I think you mean `IsNew`! It's way more common than IsDirty

Comment: @lokusking Fixed! ;)

Comment: Have an Upvote, sir ;)

Comment: @lokusking Thanks! I've even changed again interface name. `IPersistible` sounds better!

Comment: Thanks but even this check where should it be implemented ? in the serivice class ? or in the UI class? , and what would the method be called ?

Comment: @BraveHeart It's the body of a possible `AddOrUpdate`, and if you want a better place to implement it, it should be in a *repository pattern* implementation. I've opened a design pattern site some time ago where I explain the whole pattern with my own words: http://designpattern.ninja/language-agnostic/object-mapping/domain-driven-design/repository

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks for you share , but well regarding your code, I think it would be nicer if you put the isNew flag in the constructor , right ?

but secondly , So you do not think that UpdateOrAdd does break the Single responsibility principle ? )

Comment: @BraveHeart No, `IsNew` isn't a constant value but it must be evaluated in real-time, because you could say that it's new but later assign an `id > 0` and it wouldn't be new anymore. That way, same non-persistent object can become *persisted*

Comment: @BraveHeart About the SRP, this method has the single responsibility of persisting objects. Persistence approach is another story: it might be created or updated, but from the perspective of `AddOrUpdate` consumer, it's persisting the object to the underlying store. I see a single responsibility here!

Comment: @BraveHeart You would break SRP if you would also delete objects inside `AddOrUpdate`...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer well if the id is coming from the UI (e.g. social security number) , then it would be probably > 0 anyway before sending it to the database. but then the hard part would be , when would you make IsNew = false ?  Anyway for my implementation and my case i would use the getUSer and check if it exists or not, 
but for now can you update your answer and add your SRP comment please ? before I consider it as an answer

Comment: @braveheart I'll enhance it tomorrow. Now is too late here

Comment: @BraveHeart Hey, really? I see no pending edit here :/

Comment: @BraveHeart Maybe someone didn't approve your edit... :(

Comment: @BraveHeart If you want, paste it somewhere like pastebin.com and I'll take a look

Comment: @BraveHeart See my updated answer. I checked your edit and it's almost the same... I'm with the people that didn't like your edit (or even mine) because actually your question has nothing to do with SRP... BTW, I accept your concerns and it's worth the effort to add an appendix to my answer to address them :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer in this case I appologize :) any this question is onhold so do not know if people can see it or not , lets just remove all the comments which are not related to the question or the answer ,what do you think ?